# How to increase size of posted pictures from facebook api?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

```
                    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" 

                        android:padding="10dip"
                        android:background="@drawable/greybox"
                        >

                    <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/profile_pic"
                            android:layout_width="60dp"
                            android:layout_height="60dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                           /> 

                     <RelativeLayout 
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                         android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"


                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profile_pic">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/name"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Kumar"
                            android:textSize="18dp"
                            android:textColor="#4c3f38"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"


                             />


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/msg"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="15dp" 
                            android:layout_below="@+id/name"
                              android:textColor="#7b7674"

                             />



                        <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/picpostlayout"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="top|center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/msg"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/picpost"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:scaleType="fitXY"
                            android:src="@null" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/comment"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="15dp" 
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/picpostlayout"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

                            android:textColor="#000000"

                             />


                    </RelativeLayout>
                    </RelativeLayout>


    Here is my complete xml.I am using the linearlayout to show the posted picture,but it is still showing very small size.I used two relative layouts, one for complete xml and another for name,message,postpicture.
   Here is also my screenshot to the above given xml file.I am getting the large image but I cant able to show the same size,it is showing very small size.
   I got an post picture from facebook api,I am getting very large image as I used _n.jpg,but when I tried to display using imageview it is showing very small size.

        ][1] 


          [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/63nTO.png

 Here is the code of getting posted picture from facebook api.If the post object has picture field then I get that picture and changed that into large image and I added that to my ArrayList pic.

           if(jsonObject.has("picture"))
            {
            String fetchedURL = jsonObject.getString("picture");
            String getFeedPicture = fetchedURL.replaceAll("_s.jpg", "_n.jpg");
            pic.add(getFeedPicture);
            }
```

Then I send that ArrayList to my Adapter where I set that image to imageview by sending to imageloader class.
        Here is my loader class reference imageloader and I am setting image to imageview.I am setting this in my adapter class.

imageLoader.DisplayImage(postimage.get(position).replace(" ", "%20"), postimg) ;

Comment: Can you post some code to show how you are fetching the images?

Comment: webserv="https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token="+accesstoken; pic.add(jsonObject.getString("picture"));

Comment: Can you also post a screenshot of how it looks?

Comment: yes I sent my screenshot. please find it.

Comment: Are you perhaps using the Lazy Loader?

Comment: no,I am just using imageloader class to set the image

Comment: Add that Java code too. There might be something there. Also, make the 2nd `RelativeLayout` in your XML with this: `android:layout_width="fill_parent` instead of this: `android:layout_width="wrap_content`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19268/discussion-between-user1761316-and-siddharth-lele)

Answer (score 2):

Make this modification to your current code:

```
String fetchedURL = JOFeeds.getString("picture");
String getFeedPicture = fetchedURL.replaceAll("_s.jpg", "_n.jpg");
pic.add(getFeedPicture);
```

This is the simplest way to get a better quality picture from your Feeds. The whole point of this piece of code is that by default, the Facebook API returns a small version of the image. By replacing the `_s.jpg` with `_n.jpg` gives you a bigger image.

I use this code throughout my application and it works like a charm every single time.

[image: Sample Image]

And the corresponding code for this is:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linlaFeedPicture"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgvwFeedPicture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@null" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: yes I used it but when I keep wrap_content it is showing very small image Here is my xml content     <ImageView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/msg"
        android:id="@+id/picpost"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        />

Comment: Try nesting the `ImageView` in a `LinearLayout` with `android:layout_width=` set to **fill_parent**

Comment: @user1761316: I am updating the answer with a sample image from my application where I use the solution given to you.

Comment: <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/picpostlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/msg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/picpost"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@null" />
</LinearLayout>
I tried this but it is still showing small images

Comment: Please update your OP with new code. Not in comments. That being said, I believe your are using a `RelativeLayout`. Post your entire XML in the OP and let me see what I can do to try and fix the problem.

Comment: I edited my question and sended my xml.please find my xml.Thank you very much for your replies